# Copy rows to new dataframe based on change in date column and transaction

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, transactions

I've checked several websites and StackOverflow, but I wasn't able to find any documentation or help around this topic, so hoping that someone in the community might know the answer.
I have a list of groceries, quantity, transaction (B for buy and S for sell) and date purchased/sold:

```
TRANSACTIONS    Qty Transaction Date
Apple   5   B   1/1/22
Banana  5   B   1/1/22
Cereal  3   B   1/1/22
Milk    4   B   1/1/22
Banana  2   S   2/2/22
Milk    1   S   2/2/22
Toy     4   B   2/2/22
```

[image: Grocery Transactions]

What I would like to do is generate a new dataframe that incorporates the transactions to show the quantity remaining based on the transaction and each date there was a transaction:

```
BALANCE Qty Date
Apple   5   1/1/22
Banana  5   1/1/22
Cereal  3   1/1/22
Milk    4   1/1/22
Apple   5   2/2/22
Banana  3   2/2/22
Cereal  3   2/2/22
Milk    3   2/2/22
Toy     4   2/2/22
```

[image: Grocery Balance]

Comment: Please add your data as text, not images, because no one can copy/paste from images.

Comment: What is the logic?

Comment: Thank you @richardec for your suggestion. The idea is: I have a list of transactions (buy/sell) that I can input on a daily or weekly basis in a table and at the end of the day (only when there is a transaction) the table shows me what I have left based on the groceries that I bought or sold on any particular day. Like an inventory.

Comment: So basically, you want each unique `Date` to have the same items in `Balance`? I notice that `Apple` and `Cereal` were copied down into `2/2/22`, making that date have the same `Balance` items as `1/1/22`.

Comment: yes, I copied apple and cereal as well because on 2/2/22 the quantity of those items remain unchanged and adjusted the other items: 
Bananas: on Jan 1 I had 5, but I sold 2 on Feb 2, so at the end of the day on Feb 2 I have 3 banas left.
Toy: I bought 4 toys on Feb 2 (I didn't have any on Jan 1), so it is showing in the BALANCE table on Feb 2 and not Jan 1.

Comment: Okay, I see what's going on. No more explanation needed. Thank you :)

Comment: there, I'm done. Check out my very pandas-esque solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a one-liner solution (formatted):

```
new_df = (
    df.pivot(index='TRANSACTIONS', columns='Date')
    .pipe(lambda x: x.assign(Qty=x.Qty.fillna(0), Transaction=x.Transaction.ffill(axis=1)))
    .stack()
    .sort_index(level=1)
    .reset_index()
    .dropna()
    .pipe(lambda x: x.assign(Qty=x['Qty'].where(x['Transaction'] == 'B', -x['Qty'])))
    .pipe(lambda x: x.assign(Qty=x.groupby('TRANSACTIONS')['Qty'].cumsum().astype(int)))
    .drop(['Transaction'], axis=1)
    .rename({'TRANSACTIONS': 'BALANCE'}, axis=1)
)
```

Output:

```
>>> new_df
  BALANCE    Date  Qty
0   Apple  1/1/22    5
1  Banana  1/1/22    5
2  Cereal  1/1/22    3
3    Milk  1/1/22    4
5   Apple  2/2/22    5
6  Banana  2/2/22    3
7  Cereal  2/2/22    3
8    Milk  2/2/22    3
9     Toy  2/2/22    4
```

Comment: You're welcome! It was fun actually, because I've never really used `pivot` that much. This time I found a great use for it! :)